# Can I publish someone's GPL (version 2) source code to GitHub or BitBucket?

Tags: gpl, github

I obtained a GPLed (version 2) source code. But it is not maintained, and I have tried to fix some bugs. I plan to publish the code to git repository like GitHub or BitBucket. However, I cannot get the response from the source code author.

Can I publish the source code to GitHub or BitBucket without the permission of the author, since it is GPL license?

Comment: Yes of course, as long as you publish it under the same license.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By providing software under an open-source license (like the GPL license), the original author has already granted everyone with a copy of the software the right to re-publish that software, subject to some restrictions.

Which restrictions you must follow depend on the open-source license that is used. For the GPL license, those restrictions are

- All code of the project must be under the GPLv2 (or a compatible) open-source license
- If you distribute binaries, you must also distribute the corresponding source code